Ubuntu 24.04: With STP disabled, br0 interfaces still moving between fwding / blocking state
I have configured a br0 interface on ubuntu (24.04 - hosted on ESXI) with two interfaces connected to 2 switches.
/etc/netplan/90-NM-<>.yaml:
  bridges:
    br0:
      dhcp4: yes
      interfaces:
        - ens224
        - ens161
      parameters:
        stp: false

I am noticing that even though STP is disabled, the ports are moving between fwding/blocking/etc state and leading to outages.
root@labuser-VMware:/etc/netplan# brctl show
bridge name     bridge id               STP enabled     interfaces
br0             8000.be8029b6871b       no
root@labuser-VMware:/etc/netplan# 

dmesg snippet:
root@labuser-VMware:/etc/netplan# dmesg | tail -10
[163541.024614] vmxnet3 0000:13:00.0 ens224: entered allmulticast mode
[163541.024772] vmxnet3 0000:13:00.0 ens224: entered promiscuous mode
[163541.024873] br0: port 2(ens224) entered blocking state
[163541.024876] br0: port 2(ens224) entered forwarding state
[163586.003912] vmxnet3 0000:04:00.0 ens161: left allmulticast mode
[163586.004186] vmxnet3 0000:04:00.0 ens161: left promiscuous mode
[163586.004465] br0: port 1(ens161) entered disabled state
[163586.010169] vmxnet3 0000:13:00.0 ens224: left allmulticast mode
[163586.010324] vmxnet3 0000:13:00.0 ens224: left promiscuous mode
[163586.010510] br0: port 2(ens224) entered disabled state

